# Mysql DECIMAL shows cannot be cast to java.lang.Double in java spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

Hell sir ,
I have a varchar column in mysql. I want to sum varchar column value. I have done the query bellow like which works fine in mysql query. Here is my mysql query

```
select  COALESCE(SUM(CAST(taxamount as DECIMAL(9,2))),0) tax from mytable
```

In java I used bellow code for get tax data which shows j**ava.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Double**

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);

    for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
         double taxamount = (Double) row.get("tax");
   }
```

Comment: change your line to this `double taxamount = ((BigDecimal) row.get("tax")).doubleValue();`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi it shows : java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to com.ibm.icu.math.BigDecimal

Comment: looks like you have multiple classes with `BigDecimal` in that case you need to properly cast using fullname including package of class. Try this `double taxamount = ((java.math.BigDecimal) row.get("tax")).doubleValue();`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi  thanks a lot for giving last comment solution . it is working now .But my question has been duplicated...

Comment: Glad I could help. Although your issue was slightly different and your post got closed as duplicate but that's okay. It happens sometimes. What matters is your problem got resolved :)